# How to detect which part of the website causes memory leak?

Tags: jquery, css, memory-leaks

I'm currently developing a rather small website, but when I visit it through phone, my browser crashes because it uses up all of phones RAM. So I decided to check on chromes `chrome://memory-redirect/` and see how much it takes up. And it uses 170MB for something that has a top menu, image slider, accordeon menu and a footer. It shouldn't take up even a 100MB.

I tried to remove elements and refresh the page to see which element causes the leak, but couldn't find it. Are there any tools that I might use to detect the cause of this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://addyosmani.com/blog/taming-the-unicorn-easing-javascript-memory-profiling-in-devtools/) tutorial explains how to use both [Heap Profiler](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/heap-profiling) and [Timeline](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/timeline) in Chrome.

Comment: Thank you, found the cause :)